# Как правильно задать chain для template resolvers в thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

Выполняю настройку для шаблонизации писем. Объявляю `Bean`:

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver mailTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(MAIL);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(2);
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(mailTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(webTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public AjaxThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    AjaxThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new AjaxThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewClass(FlowAjaxThymeleafView.class);
    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    thymeleafViewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}
```

Оба `Bean`'а объявлены последовательно. `mail` - первый, `setOrder` у `mailResolver`'a - первый. Добавляется он в сет `resolver`'ов первый.

Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать:

```
final Context ctx = new Context(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
ctx.setVariable("name", "name");
ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", LocalDate.now());
ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));
final String htmlContent = templateEngine.process("welcomeEmail", ctx);
```

Он подставляет именно `ServletContextTemplateResolver`. Соответственно, совершенно заслуженно выдает мне:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]

Как правильно настроить?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean

public TemplateEngine templateEngine(final Set<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers)
{
    final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

    templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);


    return templateEngine;
}
```